# TCP server in C, Socket still negative

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

Hi I'm trying to run simple server-client game. Server is in C, client in java (it's school project I can't change that). My client is Windows 7 64bit and server is running on the Virtualbox (Debian 32bit) I'm using bridged connection via WiFi. I'm trying to just simply accept new connection and create new thread for it using TCP and sockets.

When I compare if `client_socket` is > 0 it's alright and client is connected. But when I put some code in the if block (commented part in code bellow) socket is -1 and it can't connect (it doesn't even reach the code). It doesn't matter what code it is even if it is `int x = 0` it will still not work. It seems like only printf() is OK. Thanks for any kind of response.

`perror()` prints "Invalid argument".

Here is my code for C server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void *serve_request(void *arg){

    printf("Thread is running.\n");
}


int start_server (void){
    int server_socket;
    int client_socket;
    int return_value;
    char cbuf;
    int *th_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_len;
    pthread_t thread_id;;

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (server_socket < 0) return -1;

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(10001);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    return_value = bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    if (return_value == 0)
     printf("Bind OK\n");
    else{
     printf("Bind Error\n");
     return -1;
    }

    return_value = listen(server_socket, 5);
    if (return_value == 0)
     printf("Listen OK\n");
    else{
     printf("Listen Error\n");
     return -1;
    }


    while(1){

     client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);

        printf("Socket number: %d\n", client_socket);

     if (client_socket >= 0 ) {

         printf("Socket OK\n");

         // #### PROBLEM PART ####
         //th_socket=malloc(sizeof(int));
         //*th_socket=client_sock;

         //thread_id = 0;
         //pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, (void *)&serve_request, (void *)th_socket);

     } else {
         printf("Socket Error\n");
         return -1;
     }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's my client_socket it's like I said without code it's positive with code it's -1. Thanks for really quick response.

Comment: Technically, `0` is a valid socket descriptor.

Comment: When any system call returns -1, you are supposed to examine the value of `errno`, or call `perror`, or print some message involving `strerror()`, to find out exactly what the error was. Without that, debugging is just a guessing game, and asking for external help is completely futile.

Comment: As for your question, are you saying that `*th_socket` is negative in the (out-commented) code you show? That it's negative in the thread function (or other code you don't show)?

Comment: I'm sorry for bad presentation. I mean client_socket is negative. perror is throwing "Invalid argument".

Comment: @Gungnir Exceptions are thrown. `perror()` does not 'throw' anything. It *prints* error messages.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry I'm more familiar with java than C

Comment: @Gungnir Java doesn't throw error messages any more than C does. You're just misusing terminology. It doesn't have anything to do with Java *versus* C. You've made the mistake of not calling `perror()` etc at several points, not just one. For example, `printf("Bind Error\n")`. Error messages of your own devising that don't contain the actual error are completely useless.

Comment: I know I just meant that in java you work with exceptions so you "throw" them. I know it's not and exception just message you're right. OK I start putting     perror     more often. I didn't about it and I just wanted to know what's going on that's way the     printf()    s. Thanks. It's good to iprove programming in any way.

Comment: `socket()` and `accept()` return -1 on error, ANYTHING ELSE is a valid socket.  That means `0` is also valid, but this code is treating `0` as an error condition when it is really not.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I thought it was also invalid. It's corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `client_addr_len` to the size of the `client_addr` structure. The `accept` function uses that argument to determine what kind of address structure is passed.

What you have now is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since uninitialized (non-static) local variables have indeterminate values (the contents of uninitialized non-static variables will be seemingly random).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was so simple it' OK now.